# JList view area grows despite adding a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlist

Here is my code:

```
protected JComponent createCommandHistory() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    listModel = new DefaultListModel();
    list = new JList(listModel);

    list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    list.addListSelectionListener(this);
    list.setVisibleRowCount(10);

    JScrollPane listScrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);

    panel.add(list);
    panel.add(new JSeparator(JSeparator.HORIZONTAL), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));

    return panel;   
}
```

As elements are added to the list, the view area grows instead of being limited by a scroller.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
panel.add(list);
```

Should be:

```
panel.add(listScrollPane);
```

Answer (score 4):

You're adding the `list` to the panel - instead, you need to add the `listScrollPane`.

In addition, when adding a component to a JPanel that has a BorderLayout, be sure to specify the position - e.g., `BorderLayout.CENTER`.

Comment: You're welcome, and glad the extra advise is helpful. Good luck!